# Get first letter after every occurence of a specific char in String

Tags: ruby

Here is my example string:

"hey_this_is_a_test"

So I would like the function to return "htiat".

I found a way like so:

```
x = "hey_this_is_a_test"
y = x.split("_")
z = ""
y.each do |w|
  z += w[0]
end

puts z
```

But I'm wondering if there is a shorter way to go about it and I feel like mine might not pass some use cases.

Comment: `x.each` or `y.each`?

Comment: Ah, y.each.  Guess that happens when you use meaningless variable names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
x = "hey_this_is_a_test"
x.split("_").map{|s| s[0]}.join # => "htiat"
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with regex.

```
"hey_this_is_a_test".scan(/^(.)|_(.)/).join
# => "htiat"
```

Plus it looks cool.

Comment: Depends on your regex level. That's a simple regex for a lot of people. I can read it faster than I can read a `split`/`join`. But that's just me.

Comment: @yeenow123, I know this is a matter of opinion, but I don't really find this solution any less readable than a string of `split`, `map`, `join`.

Comment: @mbratch It's just preference and background.

Answer (score 2):

```
"hey_this_is_a_test".gsub(/(?<=[a-z])./, "")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"hey_this_is_a_test".prepend("_").scan(/(?<=_)./).join
```